# Certbot Fails Domain Authentication

Tags: ssl, nginx, digital-ocean, ubuntu-18.04, certbot

I am stumped. I have 2 different domains that I'm trying to install an SSL cert for with Certbot on a Digital Ocean Ubuntu server. Here is the final command I run to obtain the SSL cert:

```
sudo certbot --nginx -d mydomain1.com -d www.mydomain1.com
```

I run the exact same command for `mydomain1.com` and `mydomain2.com`

Here's what makes no sense. Authentication passes for `mydomain1.com` but FAILS for `mydomain2.com`

I'm using identical Nginx Server block config files for both domains. Yes, this includes the root filepath and the server names being identical in the Nginx config file for both.

I have both the config files set to the following:

```
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

root /var/www/mydomain2.com;

index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name mydomain2.com www.mydomain2.com;
```

Yes, both config files (for `mydomain1.com` and `mydomain2.com` are set to root path of `mydomain2.com` and server name of `mydomain2.com` because I need Nginx to serve up the exact same content that I have in that directory. My intention for this was to have `mydomain1.com` redirect to `mydomain2.com` but it appears it doesn't work like that which is a separate problem. Right now I'm just trying to validate the SSL cert for `mydomain2.com` then I'll figure out the redirect.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the problem correctly, the answer is as follows:

```
certbot certonly --standalone --preferred-challenges http -d domain1.com -d www.domain1.com
```

You do not need to modify the nginx default.conf file. use the following method instead.

nano /etc/nginx/sites_available/domain1.com

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;
        return 301 https://domain1.com\$request_uri;
}
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name domain1.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain1.com/privkey.pem;
}
```

sites enabled symbolic link

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/domain1.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

The same in domain2.com